# Empty "Deleted Items" folder in Outlook via java graph sdk or api

Tags: api, outlook, microsoft-graph-sdks

Is it possible to clean up "Deleted items" folder in Outlook, not by using iteration over all items, using graph (java) sdk  or http api? Would be glad for any ideas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In EWS, use EmptyFolder operation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/gg274404(v=exchg.80)